# Passing date variable from TCL to excel

Tags: excel, csv, tcl

I'm trying to assign the date value in this format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss in a specific cell in excel, I use TCL to open excel and to parse values and finally push values to the cells in excel and finally save it in **CSV** format,

For example, when i tried to assign 2012-09-10 00:00:00 to a specific cell in excel, i see that excel converts it to 9/10/2012 0:00. Is there any way to turn off the auto formatting option in excel from TCL?

This is my sample code:

```
proc get_date  { }  {
    set date "2012-09-10 00:00:00" 
    return $date
}

set application [::tcom::ref createobject "Excel.Application"]
set workbooks [$application Workbooks]
$application DisplayAlerts False
set workbook [$workbooks Open "c:\\test\\dir\\filename.csv"]                
set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
set cells_worksheet1 [$worksheet Cells] 
$cells_worksheet1 Item 5 B [get_date]

$workbook Save
$application Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this. Here are similar discussions:

- [Excel changes date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906626/excel-changes-date-formats)
- [How to disable Excel's auto recognition of numbers and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496990/how-to-disable-excels-auto-recognition-of-numbers-and-text)
- [Formatting csv files in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788465/formatting-csv-files-in-excel)

The single-quote method only works during *export*, not *import*.  I'm using Excel 2010, and the keep-first-8-rows-blank method hasn't worked for me either.

Comment: You _can_ do it, because you can use tcom to access the Excel object model. What you can't do is ensure that it doesn't get chewed around when the CSV gets _reimported_ back into Excel; the CSV format simply doesn't keep the type metadata.

Comment: @DonalFellows - Ah, sorry, I didn't mean to deny there wasn't a way outside of using CSV. I guess I took the CSV format as a given in the asker's situation, and researched possible hacks (e.g. mentioned in the other questions: prepend-single-quote, add-blank-lines, etc.) that might cause Excel to skip formatting, but I failed to find any that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `NumberFormat` property of the range of cells that you want treated as  to `Text` (instead of the default, `General`, which guesses and changes things):

```
set cell [$cells_worksheet Item 5 B]
$cell NumberFormat "Text"
$cell Text [get_date]
```

Comment: I tried this, I get 0x800a03ec {Unable to set the Text property of the Range class}% error..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass the format by just adding an apostrophe (') to the beginning of the string which is nothing but the date,

Answer (score 0):

As [already have been explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11591712/720999), CSV does not support *any* formatting of anything — it's a plain text format.  This means that no matter which formatting you managed to set up on a sheet cell for its date/time value, when Excel saved this sheet to a CSV file, the formatting is lost, because there's no way to store it in a CSV file.

In short: stop using CSV to store your data and use native format (XLS[X]) or stop trying to make CSV handle what it can't.